# php regex put each span into next span?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have some span, the relation like this:

```
<span class="aa">word1</span><span class="bb">word2</span>...<!-- otehr html elements -->
<span class="aa">word3</span><span class="bb">word4</span>
```

how to use REGX, put **each** `span.aa` into the **next** `span.bb`?

```
<span class="bb"><span class="aa">word1</span>word2</span>...<!-- otehr html elements -->
<span class="bb"><span class="aa">word3</span>word4</span>
```

Here is something I do with `simple_html_dom.php`, but this just do whatever one group of spans, and I have many span like this situation.(there also have other html elements between spans.

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html ='<span class="aa">word1</span><span class="bb">word2</span>';
$newhtml = str_get_html($html);
$span = $newhtml->find('span', 0);
$span1 = $newhtml->find('span', 1);
echo str_replace('class="bb">','class="bb">'.$span,$span1);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Alex Howansky, too many span make me headeache. And now I studing jquery, my brain full of `each` `next` selection, so ask for a quickly help.

Comment: @Alex please find a better duplicate than the old (and wrong) slapdown "you cant" answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you need to do you could, find all `<span class="bb">`, replace them with an empty string, then find all `<span class="aa">`
and replace them with `<span class="bb"><span class="aa">`

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I also think this way, but how to? I still not find a work way both `regex` or `simple dom`, it is too dificult for me, need a help.